# mysqli prepared statement with ADDTIME CURTIME fails

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

There are so many questions on SO for failed prepared statements, but I cannot find one which solves my exact problem (or explains it, atleast).

I'm trying to give my users a login-token which is valid for 5 minutes.

When I execute the query through PHPMyAdmin it works just fine:

**WORKING QUERY**

```
INSERT INTO LOGGEDIN (userID, loggedInToken, loggedInRefresh) VALUES 
(1, "HJKFSJKFDSKLJFLS", ADDTIME(CURTIME(), '00:05:00'));
```

However, when trying to execute the query through PHP using a prepared statement it fails.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO LOGGEDIN VALUES (userID, loggedInToken, loggedInRefresh) VALUES (?, ?, ADDTIME(CURTIME(), '00:05:00'))");
$stmt->bind_param("is", $userID, $token);
```

I get the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES (?, ?, ADDTIME(CURTIME(), '00:05:00'))' at line 1
```

It is the exact same query so I think it's due to how the prepare handles the query.

I've also tried entering the '00:05:00' as a variable because I thought the ' was causing the error but it fails as well.

```
$five_minutes = '00:05:00';
$stmt->bind_param("iss", $userID, $token, $five_minutes);
```

When I remove the prepare and use the following query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO LOGGEDIN VALUES (userID, loggedInToken, loggedInRefresh) VALUES (" . $userID . ", '" . $token . "', ADDTIME(CURTIME(), '00:05:00'))";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
  ...
```

It works fine but I would like to keep my code consistent and use a prepared statement everywhere I can.

How can I let this query execute properly using a prepared statement? If all else fails I think I could create the timestamp in PHP and pass it through to the database thus bypassing the whole ADDTIME calculation, but I would like to know what is causing the problem in the first place.

Problems need to be understood, not dodged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a superfluous `VALUES` on your query:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO LOGGEDIN VALUES (userID, loggedInToken, loggedInRefresh) VALUES (?, ?, ADDTIME(CURTIME(), '00:05:00'))");
                                                    ^^
```

Remove that:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO LOGGEDIN (userID, loggedInToken, loggedInRefresh) VALUES (?, ?, ADDTIME(CURTIME(), '00:05:00'))");
```

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. Thanks!